# Polymer 1.0 - how to keep paper-dropdown-menu in the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, polymer

This is how my code looks like.

```
<div class="horizontal layout flex wrap center-justified">
  <paper-material elevation='1'>
    <div class='horizontal layout'> <span>Some Data</span> <span>
      <paper-icon-button icon='more-vert'></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-material id='drop-install'>
          <paper-menu>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap1</paper-item>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap2</paper-item>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap3</paper-item>
          </paper-menu>
        </paper-material>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
      </span> </div>
  </paper-material>
  <paper-material elevation='1'>
    <div class='horizontal layout'> <span>Some Data</span> <span>
      <paper-icon-button icon='more-vert'></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-material id='drop-install'>
          <paper-menu>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap1</paper-item>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap2</paper-item>
            <paper-item id='paper-drop-item'>Tap3</paper-item>
          </paper-menu>
        </paper-material>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
      </span> </div>
  </paper-material>
</div>
```

[image: Image1]

I am sure everything works perfectly.

[image: Image2]

but, when I am tapping on the second paper-icon-button which is at right end of the screen, the paper-dropdown-menu leaves the display.

So, I want all paper-dropdown-menus to be inside of the screen. Please support me fixing this issue.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/codepen/codesnippet?

Comment: I am using polymer 1.0 so it is not possible to create.@depperm

Comment: The best tool for sharing Polymer 1.0 right now IMHO is Plunker. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534350/how-do-i-import-polymer-1-0-elements-into-plunker-plnkr-co) for more info how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try using this styling:

```
.dropdown-content{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    }
```

on:

```
    <paper-menu-button class="flex-options">
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
                <paper-item class="item-hover">
```

I had the same problem, my content went off screen.
this styling fixed the issue for me.